# Problem in calling thread inside Eclipse view run method, after using asyncExec. Invalid Thread Exception

Tags: multithreading, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I am having an eclipse View. Inside the view I added a Table. Now I am calling a thread from run method of the view **using asyncExec**.

My View class is like -

```
public class SampleViewAction implements IWorkbenchWindowActionDelegate{

      Thread t;   

      int Count;


      @Override

      public void run(IAction arg0) {

 }
}
```

Now I added a thread like this -

```
  PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDisplay().asyncExec(new Runnable() {                   

                        @Override

                        public void run() {

                              new UDPReadThread();



                        }

                  });
```

Where UDPReadThread is a class extends a thread where in UDPReadThread 's constructor I started the thread.
But I am getting invalid Thread exception.

How to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to AWT and the EventDispatchThread, SWT must process everything in the UI thread.

Your `SampleViewAction` is run on the UI thread already, in response to a menu or tool item selection.

It looks like your problem comes from then using an `asyncExec(*)` which will post the runnable to be run on the UI thread (which delays it), and starting a **new** thread from that `asyncExec` Runnable.  You may as well simply start your thread, and get rid of that `asyncExec`.

Your `UDPReadThread` is **not** the UI thread.  If you need to update UI widgets from `UDPReadThread`, that's the code that needs the `asyncExec`:

```
display.asyncExec(
  new Runnable() {
    public void run(){
      label.setText(text);
    }
});
```

Just as an aside, you should not subclass `Thread` unless you really are extending threads capabilities.  The normal pattern when you just want to start another thread:

```
UDPReadRunnable udpRunnable = ....;
Thread thread = new Thread(udpRunnable);
thread.start();
```

You can get more information on the display thread from http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#uithread